# Segmentation fault while creating object

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

After compiling the code crashes with segmentation fault. With debugging I already figured out that segmentation fault happens during object creation:

```
PriorityQueue_1 priorityQueueYoungTableau;
```

This is PriorityQueue_1.cpp code:

[PriorityQueue_1.cpp](http://pastebin.com/ZVL66Gqj)

This is PriorityQueue_1.h code:

[PriorityQueue_1.h](http://pastebin.com/mpbGNxVp)

And this is Constants.h code:

```
#ifndef PRIORITYQUEUES_CONSTANTS_H
#define PRIORITYQUEUES_CONSTANTS_H

#include <limits.h>

const int MAX_SIZE = 25000;
const int INFINITY = INT_MAX;

#endif //PRIORITYQUEUES_CONSTANTS_H
```

I am using Clion 1.2.4 on Xubuntu 15.10

I really cannot figure out whats going on.
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Showing more code would help. How are you creating the object?  What is the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: Post [mcve] here, instead of linking to your whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `PriorityQueue_1.h`, you use array of fixed size: `int table_[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];`

You also have `MAX_SIZE=25000`;

`int table_` of `25000x25000` is something large. Assuming your `int` is 4 bytes, one `table_` takes 2.32 Gb.

So, when you create one `PriorityQueue_1` object you allocate 2.32 Gb. ***Probably, you are out of memory.***

Consider dynamic memory allocation, store only the part you currently need.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!